# How can Akka Alppaka Producer Integration with Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka

Hi every one how ca i get data with http-akka ad send to kafka with Alpakka Kafka connector and this is my source :

```
object WebTrack extends App  with  Directives with LazyLogging {
val host = "localhost"
val port = 7070

val authorization = "Authorization"

val route = withSizeLimit(96239727) {
  post {
    headerValueByName("Authorization") { auth =>
      entity(as[data]) { trans =>
        //************************** I need send data to Alpakka Kafka connector ********************************

        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
      }
    }
  }
}

val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleAsync(Route.asyncHandler(route), host, port)
.onComplete {
  case Success(_) => {
    logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:7070 \\nPress RETURN to stop...")
  }
  case Failure(e) => {
    println("Error Bind Http().bindAndHandleAsync")
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many different things that you can do with Akka Streams

Here is just one sample using a `Producer` sink, per the documentation https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html. Be sure to check out `passThrough` and some of things that it can do:

```
  implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("my-system")
  implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher

  case class User(firstName:String, lastName:String)
  object UserJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
    implicit val PortofolioFormats = jsonFormat2(User)
  }

  import UserJsonSupport._
  val config = system.settings.config.getConfig("akka.kafka.producer")
  val producerSettings = ProducerSettings(config, new StringSerializer, new StringSerializer)

  val route = withSizeLimit(96239727) {
    post {
      headerValueByName("Authorization") { auth =>
        entity(as[User]) { user: User =>
          Source.single(user)
            .map(user => new ProducerRecord[String, String]("last_names_topic", user.lastName, user.firstName))
            .runWith(Producer.plainSink(producerSettings))
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`,
            "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```